# What's the correct syntax for XSLT/XPath if/then/else?

Tags: xslt, xpath

what is the correct syntax for if/then/else using XSLT and also XPath within XSLT?

I have the following XSLT and I want to set the value of the `updateType` field to either `update` or `insert` depending on if a value exists for `PhoneID`. If `PhoneID` exists then `updateType` needs to be set to `update`, and if not it needs to be set to `insert`.

This is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//ContactPhones">
            <xsl:if test="flt:Preferred/text()='true'">
                <Result field="txtPhoneID">
                    <Value>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PhoneID"/>
                    </Value>
                </Result>



            </xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>
<Result field="updateType">
    <Value>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string(txtPhoneID)">update</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>insert</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
    </Value>
</Result>
```

How can I do this - xml input as follows:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <FWTIndividual xmlns="http://www.test.com/wsdl/FLTypes">

     <ContactPhones xmlns="">
        <PhoneID>101000047723</PhoneID>
        <Number>01923 2531345</Number>
        <DeviceType>telephone</DeviceType>
        <ns1:Usage xmlns:ns1="http://www.test.com/wsdl/FLTypes">home</ns1:Usage>

        <ns2:Preferred xmlns:ns2="http://www.test.com/wsdl/FLTypes">true</ns2:Preferred>
     </ContactPhones>

  </FWTIndividual>
```

I think the following might be a solution

```
  <Result field="updateType">
<Value>
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ContactPhones[flt:Preferred='true']">update</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>insert</xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
</Value>
```

Comment: Your probably looking for [xsl:choose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256169%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What would be the syntax in the above context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `PhoneID` element is always present in the input `ContactPhones` but can be empty, you would use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<Result field="updateType">
    <Value>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string(PhoneID)">update</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>insert</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
    </Value>
</Result>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<Result field="updateType">
    <Value>
        <xsl:value-of select="if (string(PhoneID)) then 'update' else 'insert'" />
    </Value>
</Result>
```

Otherwise the two other answers given previously will do.

--

**Note**:

Instead of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//ContactPhones">
            <xsl:if test="flt:Preferred/text()='true'">
```

consider:

```
<xsl:template match="ContactPhones[flt:Preferred='true']">
```

---

### Example:

**XML input**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <FWTIndividual xmlns="http://www.test.com/wsdl/FLTypes">
            <ContactPhones xmlns="">
                <PhoneID>123</PhoneID>
                <Number>01923 2531345</Number>
            </ContactPhones>
            <ContactPhones xmlns="">
                <PhoneID/>
                <Number>01923 2531345</Number>
            </ContactPhones>
            <ContactPhones xmlns="">
                <Number>01923 2531345</Number>
            </ContactPhones>
        </FWTIndividual>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="//ContactPhones">
            <Result field="updateType">
                <Value>
                     <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="string(PhoneID)">update</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>insert</xsl:otherwise>
                     </xsl:choose>
                </Value>
            </Result>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Result field="updateType">
      <Value>update</Value>
   </Result>
   <Result field="updateType">
      <Value>insert</Value>
   </Result>
   <Result field="updateType">
      <Value>insert</Value>
   </Result>
</root>
```

As you can see, the result is 'insert' for **both** these cases:

- `PhoneID` is empty;
- `PhoneID` is missing.

Comment: What if the PhoneID element isnt always there? I've tried the xslt 1.0 solution and whnen i have a PhoneID I get the desired result but when the PhoneID is empty the 'otherwise' isn't working so I'm assuming PhoneID element isnt always there?

Comment: "*What if the PhoneID element isnt always there?*" It will still work the same. If you're having problems with it, edit your question and show as a small. but representative example of your input.

Comment: I've updated original post. Looks like I need to do the test outside of the for each loop becuase if there are no //ContactPhones then the element wont exist. So how do I check if I've got a value in the txtPhoneID field? Looks like I might need to use a variable. If I declare a variable outside of the for each, then whats the syntax to get the phoneid into the variable within the for each and then to check the variable outside the for each.

Comment: xml input added. So if contactphones doesn't exist I still need to return updateType with an insert value

Comment: You are making it very difficult to help you. I have corrected and  minimized your input example - something you should have done yourself. I hope the example I have added to my answer makes this clear enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking about XQuery, I assume you can use XPath 2.0. With XPath 2.0, you could simply do

```
<Value>
    <xsl:value-of select="if (PhoneID) then 'insert' else 'update'"/>
</Value>
```

instead of the rather verbose `xsl:choose` (which is what you would use if you can only use XSLT and XPath 1.0).